# Trying to copy and paste some variable data

Tags: excel, vba

i'm working on a existing excel file with lots of macros and want to copy and paste variable data from 5 different sheets to 5 other sheets without copying blank cells. this is what i made so far and gives me Runtime error 1004:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheets("Hulp_IO").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("IO").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_PMSX_Lees_Tags").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Modbus_Lees_Tags_PMSX").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_PMSX_Schrijf_Tags").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Modbus_Schrijf_Tags_PMSX").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_Pakscan_Lees_Tags").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Modbus_Lees_Tags_PackScan").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_Pakscan_Schrijf_Tag").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Modbus_Schrijf_Tags_PackScan").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Start").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it say anythin more than "Runtime error"? On which row of code does the error appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code largely reviewed, because the `.Select` command is really ressource-greedy and now it is far more readable!

I don't know on which line you had the error with your code but it is an important information, so add it even if this solve your problem! ;)

Here is the code :

```
Sub Nito_Nascimento()
Dim WsFrom As Worksheet, _
    WsTo As Worksheet

    Set WsFrom = Sheets("Hulp_IO")
    Set WsTo = Sheets("IO")

    WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    WsTo.Range("B2").PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False

    Set WsFrom = Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_PMSX_Lees_Tags")
    Set WsTo = Sheets("Modbus_Lees_Tags_PMSX")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    WsTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False

    Set WsFrom = Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_PMSX_Schrijf_Tags")
    Set WsTo = Sheets("Modbus_Schrijf_Tags_PMSX")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    WsTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False

    Set WsFrom = Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_Pakscan_Lees_Tags")
    Set WsTo = Sheets("Modbus_Lees_Tags_PackScan")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    WsTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False

    Set WsFrom = Sheets("Hulp_Modbus_Pakscan_Schrijf_Tag")
    Set WsTo = Sheets("Modbus_Schrijf_Tags_PackScan")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    WsTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Start").Activate
    Set WsFrom = Nothing
    Set WsTo = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi R3uK, thanks for your help, i don't have the error anymore, it was on the first "ActiveSheet.Paste" but now the data doesn't get paste together, but it jumps 21 cells every time, do you have any ideas? Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: It jumps cells... I have no clue where this can come from... Because we are supposed to be pasting on a different sheet each time, but every time starting on `A2`, so I don't see what can happen can you be a bit more precise on the jumps? or make a screenshot?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, there was a conflict with the rest of de code in the first module, so I created a second module and added a new command button to start this macro.

Comment: is there a way I can change the code to select some specific items, like  : items 1 to 10 go to Sheet1 and 11 to 20 to Sheet2?

Comment: If by items, you mean rows, that is the line you need to modify : `WsFrom.Range("A1", WsFrom.Range("A" & WsFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy` but you'll have to duplicate it to copy/paste the first part and then copy/paste the second

Comment: @NitoNascimento : Glad I could help! ;) 

So just 2 quick pointers for that site : 
once your problem is solved, you can accept an answer (tick right under up/down votes, that'll become green) to mark your question as answered.
And use the up/down votes when you find something useful or not (question or answer)